# Standard parameters for machining aluminium?

Tags: materials, machining, aluminum, cnc

Sorry for the weird question but I was wondering about the standard machining parameters for Aluminium (if there is even a standard). Particularly the values for a CNC process (preferably in SI) for a rough volume milling and one for a finishing cut. Google searches doesn't seem to be very helpful as I only need rough values for testing purposes. (CAD Package is CREO Parametrics 2.0)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Are you talking about tolerances?  Not really sure what you mean by "parameters."

Comment: @grfrazee: [Tool angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tool_bit) and [speeds and feeds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speeds_and_feeds). The base parameters are standarized per material, and you derive the speeds and feeds from these and the tool geometry (using a [Machinist Calculator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machinist_calculator) ). Also, cooling requirements if necessary. Unfortunately, I don't have them.